# Can't hide file extension in NODE.js

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I want to hide a file extension and folder from url. So I wrote such code, that I suppose would work.
Physical path to file is /data/users.json . In url i want to get 200 response if user enteres *localhost:3000/api/users*
But I've been getting 404 . And if I enter *localhost:3000/api/users.json* - 200 instead of 404 (

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express ();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use('/api', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'data')) );

app.get('/api/:name',(req,res) => {  //http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters
    let {name}=req.params;
    
    const filename= name+'.json'; //adding extension
    
    fs.open(filename, 'r', (err, fd) => { //https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsopenpath-flags-mode-callback
        if (err) {
          if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
              console.log(filename);
            res.status(404 );
            res.end('404 '+filename);
            return;
          }
          throw err;
        }
      
        try {
          res.json(fd);
        } finally {
          close(fd, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
          });
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Don't make your `api` dir a static content dir? But even if you do, don't declare it _before_ more specific routes into `api/...` because express resolves routes in declared order. Although again: don't make your `api` dir a static content dir.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, I tried comment app.use('/api', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'data')) ); and add real path inside api.get() const filename= path.join(__dirname,'data',name+'.json'); . Fs.open gaved error          close(fd, (err) => {
          ^

ReferenceError: close is not defined

Comment: sure? `close` is not a global function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, I fixed the close error. But fs.open descripts file with "4". And using of fs.readFile(filename,'utf-8') gives me correct data.

Comment: That's not a "but", that's literally what those functions are supposed to do? `fs.open` creates a filehandle for you to use in functions that need a filehandle, and `fs.readFile` opens a file, reads the entire thing into a buffer, and then closes the file. Both do exactly what the documentation for them say they do.